# Line numbers and Syntax Highlighting don't work on different tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I am trying to resolve the issue in which `line numbers` don't work properly in `multiple tabs`. The issue is that when I create a new tab, the `line numbers` for the other tabs don't work, but the `line numbers for the current tab` does. Same goes for `syntax highlighting`.

I think the issue is in using the same variables when creating a new tab, but I have no idea how to resolve this issue and I am not sure if this is truly the problem. I was also thinking about redefining the text box, and the bindings associated with it everytime a tab is clicked.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
import traceback
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from pygments import lex
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer

import sys
import os

class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True:
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(5,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum, font=("Courier", 9))
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

        self.comment = False

class Arshi(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = "Untitled Document"
        self.content = ""
        self.previousContent = ""
        self.language = "Python"
        self.row = "0"
        self.column = "0"
        self.startCol = 0

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.menubar()
        self.bottomLabel()
        self.createtext()

    def deafultHighlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)
        self.lines = self.content.split("\n")

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", self.row + ".0")
            data = self.text.get(self.row + ".0", self.row + "." + str(len(self.lines[int(self.row) - 1])))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def highlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
            data = self.text.get("1.0", self.text.index(tk.INSERT))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def keypress(self, argument):
        self.updateBottomLabel()
        self.deafultHighlight("argument")

    def configureTags(self, text):
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Constant", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Declaration", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Namespace", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Pseudo", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Reserved", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Type", foreground="#CC7A00")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Class", foreground="#003D99")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Exception", foreground="#003D99")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Function", foreground="#003D99")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Operator.Word", foreground="#CC7A00")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Comment", foreground="#B80000")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String", foreground="#248F24")

    def createtext(self):
        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.text = CustomText(self.tab1, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))  

        self.configureTags(self.text)

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.tab1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.tab1, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text=self.fileName)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keypress)
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.keypress)

    def addtab(self):
        self.newTab = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.text = CustomText(self.newTab, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))

        self.configureTags(self.text)

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.newTab, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.newTab, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.notebook.add(self.newTab, text="Untitled Document")

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keypress)
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.keypress)

    def removetab(self):
        numberOfTabs = self.notebook.index("end")

        if numberOfTabs > 1:
            tabIndex = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select())
            self.notebook.forget(tabIndex)

    def run(self):
        pass

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New             Ctrl+N", command=self.newFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Open            Ctrl+O", command=self.openFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save            Ctrl+S", command=self.saveFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save As         Ctrl+Shift+S", command=self.saveAsFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator()
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New Window", command=self.addtab)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Close Window", command=self.removetab)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator()
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit            Alt+F4", command=self.close)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)

        self.runMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.runMenu.add_command(label="Run", command=self.run)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=self.runMenu)

    def bottomLabel(self):
        self.positionAndLanguage = tk.Label(self, text=" Ln: 1, Col: 0, Lang: Plain", anchor=tk.W, bg="#E7E7E7", font=("Courier New", 8))
        self.positionAndLanguage.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def updateBottomLabel(self):
        self.row = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[0]
        self.column = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[1]
        self.positionAndLanguage["text"] = " Ln: {0}, Col: {1}, Lang: {2}".format(self.row, self.column, self.language)

    def newFile(self):
        self.fileName = "Untitled"
        self.previousContent = ""
        self.text.delete(0.0, tk.END)

    def openFile(self):
        try:
            self.fileName = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename() #Asks user to open file
            with open(self.fileName, 'r') as file:
                self.content = file.read() #Reads content typed
            self.text.delete(0.0, tk.END) 
            self.text.insert(0.0, self.content)
            self.highlight(self)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error occured.")

    def deleteContent(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()

    def saveFile(self):
        self.content = self.text.get(0.0, tk.END)

        try:
            with open(self.fileName, 'w') as file:
                self.deleteContent(file)
                file.write(self.content)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error occured.")

    def saveAsFile(self):
        self.content = self.text.get(0.0, tk.END)

        try:
            self.fileName = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
            if self.fileName != None:
                with open(self.fileName, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(self.content)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexcepted error occured.")

    def close(self):
        try:
            os._exit(0)
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Arshi")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Arshi(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you observed, the issue is because you are always changing the `linenumbers` to the linenumber of the latest tab, so for old tabs , even if the `_on_change()` is called, it would call redraw only on the new line number, not on the old ones.

I believe the correct way to go forward for your application would be to have another level of abstraction, where `Tab` is a complete object by itself, and each tab should be a different object and should keep store the linenumber/text in itself.

Example -

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True:
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(5,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum, font=("Courier", 9))
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

        self.comment = False

class Tab:
    def __init__(self, parent, filename):
        self.parent = parent
        self.filename = filename
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(parent)
        self.text = CustomText(self.tab1, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.tab1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.tab1, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        parent.add(self.tab1, text=filename)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()


class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = "Untitled Document"
        self.content = ""
        self.previousContent = ""
        self.language = "Python"
        self.row = "0"
        self.column = "0"
        self.startCol = 0

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.tabs = []
        self.menubar()
        self.createtext()

    def createtext(self):
        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        t = Tab(self.notebook, self.fileName)
        self.tabs.append(t)

    def addtab(self):
        t = Tab(self.notebook, self.fileName)
        self.tabs.append(t)

    def removetab(self):
        numberOfTabs = self.notebook.index("end")

        if numberOfTabs > 1:
            tabIndex = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select())
            self.notebook.forget(tabIndex)
            del self.tabs[tabIndex]

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New Window", command=self.addtab)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Close Window", command=self.removetab)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Window")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Window(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I created a new class `Tab` and copied code from previous methods like `createtext` into it, and now when creating a new tab, we just need to instantiate object of `Tab` class.

---

Partially working code , for your case -

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
import traceback
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from pygments import lex
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer

import sys
import os

class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True:
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(5,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum, font=("Courier", 9))
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

        self.comment = False

class Tab:
    def __init__(self, parent, filename, parentwindow):
        self.fileName = "Untitled Document"
        self.content = ""
        self.previousContent = ""
        self.parentwindow = parentwindow
        self.language = "Python"
        self.parent = parent
        self.filename = filename
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(parent)
        self.text = CustomText(self.tab1, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.tab1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.tab1, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        parent.add(self.tab1, text=filename)
        self.bottomLabel()

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keypress)
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.keypress)

    def deafultHighlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)
        self.lines = self.content.split("\n")

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", self.row + ".0")
            data = self.text.get(self.row + ".0", self.row + "." + str(len(self.lines[int(self.row) - 1])))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def highlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
            data = self.text.get("1.0", self.text.index(tk.INSERT))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def keypress(self, argument):
        self.updateBottomLabel()
        self.deafultHighlight("argument")

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()

    def bottomLabel(self):
        self.positionAndLanguage = tk.Label(self.parentwindow, text=" Ln: 1, Col: 0, Lang: Plain", anchor=tk.W, bg="#E7E7E7", font=("Courier New", 8))
        self.positionAndLanguage.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def updateBottomLabel(self):
        self.row = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[0]
        self.column = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[1]
        self.positionAndLanguage["text"] = " Ln: {0}, Col: {1}, Lang: {2}".format(self.row, self.column, self.language)

class Arshi(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = "Untitled Document"
        self.content = ""
        self.previousContent = ""
        self.language = "Python"
        self.row = "0"
        self.column = "0"
        self.startCol = 0
        self.tabs = []
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.menubar()
        #self.bottomLabel()
        self.createtext()

    def deafultHighlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)
        self.lines = self.content.split("\n")

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", self.row + ".0")
            data = self.text.get(self.row + ".0", self.row + "." + str(len(self.lines[int(self.row) - 1])))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def highlight(self, argument):
        self.content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

        if (self.previousContent != self.content):
            self.text.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
            data = self.text.get("1.0", self.text.index(tk.INSERT))

            for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
                self.text.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
                self.text.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
                self.text.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        self.previousContent = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)

    def keypress(self, argument):
        self.updateBottomLabel()
        self.deafultHighlight("argument")

    def configureTags(self, text):
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Constant", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Declaration", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Namespace", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Pseudo", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Reserved", foreground="#CC7A00")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Type", foreground="#CC7A00")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Class", foreground="#003D99")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Exception", foreground="#003D99")
        text.tag_configure("Token.Name.Function", foreground="#003D99")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Operator.Word", foreground="#CC7A00")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Comment", foreground="#B80000")

        text.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String", foreground="#248F24")

    def createtext(self):
        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        t = Tab(self.notebook, self.fileName, self)
        self.tabs.append(t)

    def addtab(self):
        t = Tab(self.notebook, self.fileName, self)
        self.tabs.append(t)

    def removetab(self):
        numberOfTabs = self.notebook.index("end")

        if numberOfTabs > 1:
            tabIndex = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select())
            self.notebook.forget(tabIndex)

    def run(self):
        pass

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New             Ctrl+N", command=self.newFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Open            Ctrl+O", command=self.openFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save            Ctrl+S", command=self.saveFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save As         Ctrl+Shift+S", command=self.saveAsFile)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator()
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New Window", command=self.addtab)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Close Window", command=self.removetab)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator()
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit            Alt+F4", command=self.close)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)

        self.runMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.runMenu.add_command(label="Run", command=self.run)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=self.runMenu)

    def bottomLabel(self):
        self.positionAndLanguage = tk.Label(self, text=" Ln: 1, Col: 0, Lang: Plain", anchor=tk.W, bg="#E7E7E7", font=("Courier New", 8))
        self.positionAndLanguage.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def updateBottomLabel(self):
        self.row = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[0]
        self.column = self.text.index(tk.INSERT).split(".")[1]
        self.positionAndLanguage["text"] = " Ln: {0}, Col: {1}, Lang: {2}".format(self.row, self.column, self.language)

    def newFile(self):
        self.addtab()

    def openFile(self):
        try:
            self.fileName = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename() #Asks user to open file
            with open(self.fileName, 'r') as file:
                self.content = file.read() #Reads content typed
            self.text.delete(0.0, tk.END) 
            self.text.insert(0.0, self.content)
            self.highlight(self)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error occured.")

    def deleteContent(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()

    def saveFile(self):
        self.content = self.text.get(0.0, tk.END)

        try:
            with open(self.fileName, 'w') as file:
                self.deleteContent(file)
                file.write(self.content)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error occured.")

    def saveAsFile(self):
        self.content = self.text.get(0.0, tk.END)

        try:
            self.fileName = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
            if self.fileName != None:
                with open(self.fileName, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(self.content)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Error reading file.")
        except:
            print("Unexcepted error occured.")

    def close(self):
        try:
            os._exit(0)
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Arshi")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Arshi(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Currently, `open()` would not work , and the bottom labels come up duplicated for each tab, you should think about how to work those out. The bottom label one can move out of `Tab` class back to `Arshi` , and then have some communication between `Tab` class and `Arshi` when tabs are changed to change the bottom label accordingly.

Also, open should open a new tab, so you can easily work on that. I would also advice you to understand the complete code and then use it in your code , rather than just copy-paste.

Comment: This worked but I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Tab' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: When do you get that?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I really do appreciate it. I was trying to translate this code to my main text editor, which included syntax highlighting too. It worked on my basic one which didn't include syntax highlighting, but it didn't work on my more advanced one. I have updated the code to show the advanced text editor. It would be amazing if you could help me out on that.

Comment: Let me check it out , I will try to check in some time .

Comment: I got everything to work except for the bottom label.